# Find the Probability of 2 Numbers A and B from Interval

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

```
Two numbers A and B are selected from the interval [−3, 2] with uniform 
distribution.

(A) What is the joint probability density function for A and B?
```

This is what I got, is it correct? If not, how do I figure this out?
        f(A,B) = 1/total area = f(A,B) = 1/5

```
(B) What is the probability that A < B and B > 1?

P(B>1) = 1/5, right?   P(A < B) = I am really not sure how to get this part.
P((B>1) & (A<B)) = P(B>1) + P(A<B) - P(B>1 intersection A<B), right?


(C) What is the probability that |A − B | < 1?
```

p(|A-B| <1) =  P(-1 < A - B < 1), right? How to solve this? Sorry, I am just really confused.

Comment: I think that the total area of a $5 \times 5$ rectangle may be $25$.  You can then draw lines on that rectangle to solve (B) and (C)

Comment: @Heather:...5x5=25... Besides, and more important, did anybody hint that these random variables are independent?

Comment: You should give more information about how $A$ and $B$ are selected. If they are just selected at random independently from each other then the joint probability density function is the product. If you want $A$ and $B$ not to be independent we need some more information about their correlation.